# Declare and Using Variables inside an SSRS-Expression?

Tags: reporting-services

You can use in SSRS-Expression like this:

```
=IIf(Fields!YearlyIncome.Value >= 60000,"High","Low")
```

But is it possible to declare and using variable inside: I did not found any information about in at the internet.

```
= DECLARE @column_name as String = YearlyIncome

= IIf(Fields!@column_name.Value >= 60000,"High","Low")
```

Comment: As far as I know you can't do this. You can set report variables, update them via custom code in SSRS and then reference them in expressions. Have a look at this https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3231/sql-server-reporting-services-report-and-group-variable-references/#:~:text=Like%20other%20objects%20within%20a,code%20or%20external%20code%20references.